# Are the reals really a fraction field?

Tags: axiom-of-choice, fields

In an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/743985/3217) I was led to show the  trick proving that $\mathbb R$ is the fraction field of some strict subring $A\subsetneq \mathbb R=\operatorname{Frac}(A)$.
A crucial point in the trick  is  the existence of a transcendence basis of $\mathbb R$ over  $\mathbb Q$.
So this necessitates the axiom of choice and I would be grateful to a savvy user for confirming (or infirming) my feeling  that the existence of such an $A$ is indeed only possible under acceptance of the axiom of choice.

Comment: I have a feeling that you might be able to show that $A$ cannot have the Baire property; or maybe Lebesgue measurability; or that it cannot be Borel; or something like that. In either of these cases it seems that the axiom of choice is needed.

Comment: Georges, being not quite fluent in algebra; in your answer on MSE, when you consider the $A$ to be the integral closure of $\Bbb Q[r_i\mid i\in I]$, does every permutation of the $r_i$'s induce an automorphism of $A$, and can that automorphism be extended uniquely to an automorphism of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Dear @Asaf, every automorphism of $A$ can be extended to an automorphism of $\mathbb R$ (apply the automorphism to the numerator and the denominator of a fraction), but I'm far for sure that every permutation of the $r_i$'s can be extended to $A$ .

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer. If we can show that there are $2^\frak c$ automorphisms of $A$ then it certainly can't be doable without the axiom of choice (it is consistent there are only $\frak c$ automorphisms of $\Bbb R$ as an additive group). Of course it doesn't mean the entire result fails, just this particular approach, but it would be a first step, I suppose.

Comment: The funny thing is that one can easily construct a proper additive subgroup $A$ of $\mathbb R$ that generates $\mathbb R$ as a ring without AC. I surmise you know that already, but, once you observe that, the belief that the existence theorem in your question really requires AC gets somewhat shaken, doesn't it?

Comment: @fedja could you explain how this subgroup A is constructed?